# Buildspec.yml file position in my terraform project

Tags: terraform, aws-codebuild, buildspec

So, I have a big terraform folder where I put all my work with terraform. In that terraform folder I have a terraform-project subfolder which is a structured terraform project with modules, environments, etc. I was wondering where should I put my buildspec.yml file so my aws_codebuild_project will see it. I tried putting it in the modules folder, on the same level as module folder and on the same level as terraform-project folder.
[This is how my terraform folder looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lyub.png).

The aws_codebuild_project looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oY78r.png)  and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CeuE.png).

I use the code build in environment like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blJF8.png).

When I run the pipeline, at build stage I always get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnKdA.png).

Comment: How exactly do you use codebuild? What is your input source? How did you setup your codebuild project?

Comment: I updated the post, I couldn't put pictures as comment.

Comment: Sadly the question is no clear. Can you describe, step by step, how anyone could reproduce the issue on their own?

Comment: So all the modules creates a working pipeline which uses ecs blue/green deployment and deploys an image from an ecr repository when I use 'terraform apply' in one of my 3 environments. Each environment uses the folders from the 'modules' folder using the module resource. I added code build so I can do image scanning on the build stage. I want to know where should I put the buildspec.yml file so my aws_codebuild_project will see here. I know that the buildspec.yml file should be on root level, but in my structure I don't really know which one is the root.

Comment: In the environment folder I have 3 folders called dev, prod and qa where in the main.tf file I 'link' the folders from 'modules' folder using the aws module resource.